# Absolute path ES6 module import typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, es6-modules, tsconfig

I'm currently searching since hours how to import local ES6 modules with an absolute path.

Whenever I try to import something in a module like :

```
import { Module } from "src/my-module";
```

I get an error "Error: Cannot find module 'src/my-module'. Here is my tsconfig :

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"lib": \["ES6"\],
"target": "ES6",
"baseUrl": "./",
"rootDir": "src",
"esModuleInterop": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
}
"include": \["src/\*\*/\*.ts"\],
"exclude": \["node_modules"\]
}
```

I tried to fill the paths attribute of compilerOptions in tsconfig, modifying baseUrl, installing typescript-transform-paths, ilearnio/module-alias ...
I'm using ts-node

Comment: Absolute path is path starting from disk letter, I assume you don't want to do it. What is your goal?

Comment: Your error `Cannot find module 'src/my-module` is self-explanatory - it means your module is not inside the folder you are trying to import it from. Make sure you are importing it from the correct directory.

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli Relative to the project's main folder

Comment: @Aleksandar Visual studio is higlighting it and isn't detecting any problem, the file exists in the specified folder but when I run tsnode, it tells that the module doesn't exist

Comment: @Aleksandar `import { Module } = require("src/my-module");` isn't a valid operation, we can't assign require to an import definition

Answer (score 2):

Oh my god, I fianlly found after so much time spent to search for an answer ...
I had to add

```
{
// ....
"ts-node": {
    // Do not forget to `npm i -D tsconfig-paths`
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
 }
"compilerOptions" {
    // ....
}
// ....
}
```

to my tsconfig.json and it's working !

Comment: could you cleanup your answer's formatting a bit? I'm not clear on what the solution is.

Comment: @Slbox Done sorry :)